# Django Collect Static says 0 static files copied

Tags: python, django, collectstatic

I want to get run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

To collectstatic. For development. It wokring on localhost but when i host on any other server it's not working
But it says

```
0 static files copied to....
```

Here in my setting.py looks like that.
I have static folder in my root folder and still not working evertime it says 0 static files copied to ... and I think because of it now my admin page looks like with out CSS

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLawZ.png)

## Settings.py code

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
import os
from pathlib import Path

import cloudinary
import cloudinary.uploader
import cloudinary.api

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = True
DEBUG = False

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".vercel.app", ".now.sh",
                 "127.0.0.1", "localhost", "192.168.1.9"]


# Application definition

EXTERNAL_APPS = [
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'Blog',
    'Account',
    'cloudinary',
    'cloudinary_storage',
    "ckeditor",
    


]

BUILD_IN_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


]  # ADDING EXTERNAL APPS
INSTALLED_APPS = EXTERNAL_APPS + BUILD_IN_APPS

MAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Blogging.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Blogging.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {



     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }

}


....



STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')


MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

...

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# FOR BOOTSTRAP MESSAGE
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger'
}

# CLOUDINARY settings for ONLINE FILES.
cloudinary.config(
    cloud_name=os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME'),
    api_key=os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'),
    api_secret=os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET')
)
```